# mIRC - Pausing hash table

Tags: irc, mirc, twitch

Code;

```
on *:text:!ticket *:#:{
 var %hash $+(ticket.,#) 
  if $istok(%owner,$nick,32) && $2 == on && !$hget(%hash) { 
    hmake %hash 
    msg # Ticket now is open. Use !ticket <point> to join.
  }
  elseif $2 isnum && $2 > 0 && $hget(%hash) {
    var %topic $+(#,.,$nick), %point $readini(points.ini,%topic,points)
    if %point >= $2 {
      var %p $calc(%point - $2)
      writeini points.ini %topic points %p 
      var %i $hget(%hash,0).item, %t $calc(%i + $2) 
      while %i < %t { inc %i | hadd %hash %i $nick }
      msg # $nick $+ , You bought $2 ticket, you now have %p points
   }
    else { msg # $nick Sorry, you only have %point points }
  }
  elseif ($nick isop #) && $2 == roll && $hget(%hash) {
    var %i $rand(1,$hget(%hash,0).data)
    msg # The winner is $hget(%hash,%i).data $+ . 
    //I want to pause the raffle here so no more people can buy tickets but it sill keeps the entrys
  }
   elseif ($nick isop #) && $2 == over && $hget(%hash) {
        hfree %hash
  }
    elseif ($nick isop #) && $2 == go && $hget(%hash) {
            //I want people to be allowed to by more tickets and have the old tickets still count
  }
}
```

It's all good. I just need to be able to pause the raffle but not get rid of the entries and then be able to resume the raffle. Comments in code to explain

Comment: to "pause" a game, when an OP type "roll" you can use something like this


    inc -u10 %pause
    if (!%pause) { comamand }

in this way, you will create a variable that will be set for 10 seconds and then unset itself

Comment: Can you post it as code for me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the part you want

```
on *:text:!ticket *:#:{
var %hash $+(ticket.,#) 
if $istok(%owner,$nick,32) && $2 == on && !$hget(%hash) { 
hmake %hash 
msg # Ticket now is open. Use !ticket <point> to join.
}
elseif $2 isnum && $2 > 0 && $hget(%hash) {
var %topic $+(#,.,$nick), %point $readini(points.ini,%topic,points)
if %point >= $2 && !%pause {
// here script will check if %pause is not set, so script will run normal, if yes, it wont work
  var %p $calc(%point - $2)
  writeini points.ini %topic points %p 
  var %i $hget(%hash,0).item, %t $calc(%i + $2) 
  while %i < %t { inc %i | hadd %hash %i $nick }
  msg # $nick $+ , You bought $2 ticket, you now have %p points
 }
else { msg # $nick Sorry, you only have %point points }
}
elseif ($nick isop #) && $2 == roll && $hget(%hash) {
var %i $rand(1,$hget(%hash,0).data)
msg # The winner is $hget(%hash,%i).data $+ . 
inc -u10 %pause
//10 is time in seconds you can choose whatever time you want, so in this way, no one  can buy tickets for 10 seconds
}
elseif ($nick isop #) && $2 == over && $hget(%hash) {
hfree %hash
}
elseif ($nick isop #) && $2 == go && $hget(%hash) {
unset %pause
// if someone typed "roll" and then you want to buy more tickes, typing "go" will just unset %pause
// you can set %pause for more time, or just an unlimmited time
}
}
```

i didnt test it yet

Comment: Thanks! Will let you know when I test it. A bit unrelated by how do I put a limit. So a person can only buy ten tickes?

Comment: It's a twitch irc bot

Comment: I got steam ImSeanDowney.. Send me the answer there? :)

Comment: I've posted a new question

Comment: you can use an .ini file or variables example
 if ($($+(%,$1),2) <= 9) {
    inc $+(%,$1) 1
    echo -ag Added 1 ticket to $v1
  }
  else {
    msg $chan $v1 cant have more Points
  }
}

Comment: So can I keep the hashtable and limit it?

Comment: I am not currently at my pc but will let you know